# Как задать некий диапазон в подборе, выводить строки со значением подходящим в пределах от 0,1 до 1 от введеного значения?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Del_11.csv', sep=';')
kW = input('Введите мощность: ')

print(df[df["Мощность\n [kW]"] == kW])
```

Колонка "Мощность\n [kW]" содержит не целые числа, например 19.8, 12.5 и т.д, а в переменной kW введено целое число например 19

Comment: а зачем указывать нижний предел? если значение в строке отличается от введенного на 0.0001, то оно не нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в общем случае ничего сложного-то нет. При исходных

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"kw":[10, 12, 12.3, 14, 12.5, 19, 13, 5]})
```

df:

```
     kw
0  10.0
1  12.0
2  12.3
3  14.0
4  12.5
5  19.0
6  13.0
7   5.0
```

делаем простую выборку:

```
v = 12.5 # введенное число
res = df[abs(df["kw"]-v) <=1]
```

res:

```
     kw
1  12.0
2  12.3
4  12.5
6  13.0
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' : вот такое выдает, нужно судя по всему к int привести значения колонки?

Comment: значит у вас в датафрейме не числа, а строки. и инпут у вас по молчанию строковый.

Comment: в итоге нужно во всем датафрейме сменить тип данных или я не так понимаю?

Comment: сначала переведите input свой в число: `kW = int(input('Введите мощность: '))` или `kW = float(input('Введите мощность: '))`. а потом попробуйте `res = df[abs(df["kw"].astype(float)-v) <=1]`

Comment: kW = float(input('Введите мощность: '))

kW_1 = df[abs(df["Мощность\n [kW]"].astype(float)-kW) <=1]

print(kW_1)  ValueError: could not convert string to float: '14,6' -

Comment: заранее извиняюсь за настойчивость!

Comment: ну, то есть вы действительно считаете, что вещественные числа в питоне имеют десятичным разделителем запятую? даже у меня в примере не "12,5"   ,а "12.5"

Comment: Спасибо! Все пока получилось